# Java illegal start of type error for return statement in string builder, why is this happening?

Tags: java

I am attempting to output the results of a complementary dna sequence but i am needing to show output as a string so ive designed a string builder to give me my output as a string but I am receiving an illegal start of type error for the return statement. Why am I receiving this error? I've looked over everything and nothing seems to stick out to me.

```
public class Homework_two{
static Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
static ArrayList <String> complementarySequence = new ArrayList <>();
static ArrayList <Character> templateStrand = new ArrayList <>();
public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println("Please enter the FASTA sequence.");
    String FASTA_Sequence = keyb.nextLine();
    //templateStrand.add(FASTA_Sequence);
    //compute_complimentary_sequence(templateStrand);
    
    
    for(char ch: FASTA_Sequence.toCharArray()){
        templateStrand.add(ch);
        compute_complimentary_sequence(ch);
        
    }
    //System.out.println("complementary Sequence without commas equals " + complementarySequence.join(""));
    System.out.println("Your entered FASTA Sequence is "+ templateStrand + " your complimentary sequence is " + System.out.println(arrayListToString(complementarySequence)));
}

static void compute_complimentary_sequence(Character nucleotide){
    
    Map <Character, Character> WatsonCrickPairs = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    WatsonCrickPairs.put('A','T');
    WatsonCrickPairs.put('T','A');
    WatsonCrickPairs.put('G','C');
    WatsonCrickPairs.put('C','G');
    
    for(Map.Entry nc : WatsonCrickPairs.entrySet()){
        Character key = (Character)nc.getKey();
        Character value = (Character)nc.getValue();
        if(nucleotide == key){
            complementarySequence.add(Character.toString(value));
            
     
        }

    }
        
} 
static String arrayListToString(ArrayList<String> list){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    for(String nc2 : list){
        sb.append(nc2);
    }
}   return sb.toString();
```

}

Comment: Because the return isn't in your method.

Answer (score 1):

Because your return statement should locate in another section.

```
    static String arrayListToString(ArrayList<String> list){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        for(String nc2 : list){
            sb.append(nc2);
        }
       return sb.toString();
}
```